# How to order table data when using $wpdb->get_results

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to order the data by a date value stored in the database. This is how I am getting my data;

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT * FROM wp_events WHERE user_id = "'.$user_id.'" ORDER by event_date ASC');
```

I have column in my wp_events tab called event_date using the following format dd-mm-yyyy I want to be able to order my data using the values stored in this column. Is this possible?

Comment: Try this: `SELECT * FROM wp_events WHERE user_id = "'.$user_id.'" ORDER by DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(event_date , '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') ASC`

Comment: @Zak I altered your code a little to 'ORDER by DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE(event_date , '%d-%m-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d')' ASC and that sorts them using the day and month but not year

Comment: "I am trying to order the data by a date value" No, you're trying to order by a string value. Why not just set up your database properly?

Comment: @miken32 is correct ..  `event_date ` should really be `DATE_TIME` not `VARCHAR`

Comment: @miken32 yes you are correct but I'm importing the websites old database and this is how they set it up so I didn't want to change it